# Django : dynamically update via request.data error

Tags: python, django

```
Stock.objects.get(id=1).update(
    **request.data
)
data = request.data
print(data)
```

I get this -

```
<QueryDict: {'discount_margin': ['77'], 'rack': ['77'], 'demand': ['77']}>
```

I am getting this - 
float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

Comment: .update works with filter not get, try this `Stock.objects.filter(id=1).update(**request.data)`

Comment: tried with filter both give same error- float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

Comment: Please post the code of fields in models.py for Stock Table

Comment: And the full traceback.

Comment: can please explain a little bit?
why is this not working?
.update(
    **request.data
)

Comment: Can you share your models.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by this-

```
update_data = {}
for key in request.data.keys():
   update_data[key] = request.data[key]

instance.update(
   **update_data
)
```